# How to write a rule to prevent any deletion of node from database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to write rules to secure database. But I am confused on writing a rule which will prevent from deleting any node from database. I have read regarding `newData.exists`but when I tried running it in simulator deletion was succeeded! As a node can be deleted by setting its value to null, so I tried simulating the value of node to null and it was successful, which was not desired.

Suppose I have this node:

```
root{
Number of Users:20
}
```

And I wrote these rules:

```
"Number of Users":{
".read":true,
 ".write":"auth!==null && newData.exists()"
 }
```

Am I making any mistake, please correct me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To allow adding new nodes, but prevent deleting or overwriting any node:

```
".write": "!data.exists()"
```

To allow adding and overwriting, but not deleting, any node:

```
".write": "newData.exists()"
```

**Update: screenshot of the simulator for these rules**
[image: Cannot write null]

Comment: I am using newData.exists() anded with auth!=null and by setting the value of that node =null, that node is deleted. how do I prevent it? I have checked in simulator.

Comment: I just tested and added a screenshot of my simulator rejecting a null.

Comment: I got it. I was not using simulator correctly. I was simulating by adding a null value to new node under that node instead of writing a null to that node itself!