# Firebase Database Prevent Deletion of Node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

".write": "newData.exists()"

[The rule above is from this Stackoverflow answer showing how to prevent deletion of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919866/how-to-write-a-rule-to-prevent-any-deletion-of-node-from-database)

I used the same rule but my data is getting deleted. Shown below is my data schema. Could it be that the rule in the article doesn't work on my data because of a different data schema?

Edit:
Here is my rules:[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the full set of security rules **as well as** code you use for the deletion. A security rule should always be analyzed together with the corresponding queries.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited my post to include my rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the SO answer you refer to in your question, in order to **prevent deleting** any node you should use

```
".write": "!data.exists()"
```

More details on the `data` and `newData` variables in the [doc on RTDB Security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#data).